# Compile error during running Selenium tests remotely from jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, ssh, junit

I am trying to run selenium tests from a remote machine through Jenkins (Jenkins is running as root). I am able to run the tests perfectly by SSH through terminal but when I try to run the tests from Jenkins, I get the error mentioned below:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace [workspace path]
SSH: Connecting from host [host-name]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [ruser name] ...
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [command to run] ...
Test Location:          [location]
Test started at:             2013-01-21T16:36:44
Test in Progress...
...starting events generation
SalesforceHome.java:3: error: package com.thoughtworks.selenium does not exist
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
^
SalesforceHome.java:4: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.After;
                ^
SalesforceHome.java:5: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Before;
                ^
SalesforceHome.java:6: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
                ^
SalesforceHome.java:7: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          ^
SalesforceHome.java:8: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
                          ^
SalesforceHome.java:9: error: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
                                 ^
SalesforceHome.java:10: error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
                                  ^
SalesforceHome.java:11: error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
                                  ^
SalesforceHome.java:12: error: package org.openqa.selenium.remote does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
                                 ^
SalesforceHome.java:13: error: package org.openqa.selenium.remote does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
                                 ^
SalesforceHome.java:20: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                       ^
SalesforceHome.java:21: error: package org.apache.log4j.xml does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
                           ^
SalesforceHome.java:22: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.*;
^
SalesforceHome.java:23: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
                       ^
SalesforceHome.java:24: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;
                       ^
SalesforceHome.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
public class SalesforceHome extends SeleneseTestBase{
                                    ^
  symbol: class SeleneseTestBase
SalesforceHome.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
Logger logger;
^
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    @Before
     ^
  symbol:   class Before
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
    @After
     ^
  symbol:   class After
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
         logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
                                       ^
  symbol: method getClass()
SalesforceHome.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
         logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
                  ^
  symbol:   variable Logger
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
        ^
  symbol:   variable DOMConfigurator
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
          WebDriver driver = conf.setConf(BName);
          ^
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:51: error: cannot access WebDriver
          WebDriver driver = conf.setConf(BName);
                                         ^
  class file for org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver not found
SalesforceHome.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
                  if (driver instanceof RemoteWebDriver) 
                                        ^
  symbol:   class RemoteWebDriver
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
                  ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setLogLevel(Level.OFF);
                    ^
  symbol:   class RemoteWebDriver
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
          selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
          ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
          selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
                         ^
  symbol:   class WebDriverBackedSelenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
selenium.setTimeout("1000000");
^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
                selenium.open("/");
                ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.type("id=", "");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.type("id=", "");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.click("id=");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("150000");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.click("link=");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("150000");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.type("id=", "");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.click("id=");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("150000");
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
SalesforceHome.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
        selenium.stop();
        ^
  symbol:   variable selenium
  location: class SalesforceHome
42 errors
Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [machine name] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec timed out or was interrupted after 4,067 ms]
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1293805758975477494.sh
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please tell us HOW you run tests on Jenkins and what you do for these to run fine via SSH. Is it a `mvn test` with Maven ? It looks like you have serious classpath issues, so Jenkins doesn't prepare your environnement correctly. Do you have a build script ? Ant, maybe ?

Comment: Well, I have these tests placed on a remote machine. I simply ssh into that machine through terminal of my machine and run a simple script file to run the tests. These are selenium based tests, thus require selenium environment.. I believe (may be I am wrong), for some reason, when I ssh through Jenkins to this machine, and run scripts from jenkins shell, it is not able to fetch the environment variables or setup the environment thus resulting in this error..

Comment: It is compile error. Some how all necessary jar files are not available, such as jar file for junit, selenium